# Force Jetpack to not use og:image tag for favicon / Site Icon

Tags: plugin-jetpack

My blog (Jetpack) sends out `512x512` favicon as `og:image`, because theme used does not support featured images and there are no images / gallery in the post itself. I'm forced to use favicons that large, because Wordpress / theme says:

> The Site Icon is used as a browser and app icon for your site. Icons must be square, and at least 512 pixels wide and tall.

Is there any solution, that would allow me to block `og:image` tag **only for favicon** (i.e. if there will be any images directly in post text or if I change my theme to one, that supports featured images, I want them to be exported as `og:image`; I only want to block sending favicon / Site Icon through this tag).

**Edit**: *As per [Jetpack Blog](https://jetpack.com/2013/10/15/add-a-default-fallback-image-if-no-image/) I have assumed, that the quickest solution will be to ignore above text and set my favicon to i.e. `192x192`, which Facebook should ignore. However, some tests with [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) showed, that this not always works (image isn't sometimes ignored) and this will certainly not work for other kind of social sharing services. Thus, an ability to blog `og:image` tag for favicons / Site Icons becomes really necessary.*

Comment: Right now since favicon/site-icon you are using is 512x512px , it is not ignored.

Comment: @bravokeyl: You're correct. However, this is some kind of dead circle. I must have favicon 32x32 to have Facebook ignore it and in the same time I must have it 512x512, because Wordpress / my theme tells me so: "_The Site Icon is used as a browser and app icon for your site. Icons must be square, and at least 512 pixels wide and tall_". For this reason I was forced to re-edit this question entirely. See, if you can adapt your answer to changed question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Probably through Jetpack, yet I'm not sure

Looking at your site now I can say that those open graph tags are from `Jetpack` Plugin.

---

If there is no image available in the post , Jetpack adds site-icon/favicon as the default one.

We can control output of tags using filters

- **`jetpack_open_graph_tags`**
- **`jetpack_images_get_images`**
- **`jetpack_open_graph_image_default`**
- **`jetpack_enable_open_graph`**

## Remove only og:image

Place the following code in `functions.php` of the active theme.

```
function wpse_228649_remove_image_tag( $tags ) {
      unset( $tags['og:image'] );
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_open_graph_tags', 'wpse_228649_remove_image_tag' );
```

Stating from [Jetpack blog](https://jetpack.com/2013/10/15/add-a-default-fallback-image-if-no-image/)

Jetpack starts by looking for a Featured Image. If you didn’t define any, we will look for slideshows and galleries, and then for any images that may be attached to the post. If we don’t find any image attached to that post, we’ll look for single images you may have inserted in the post. If you’ve inserted an image that is hosted on another site, we can use it too.

However, sometimes you may not have added any image to your post. 
In that case , we can set default image using the following code.

```
function wpse_203094_custom_image( $media, $post_id, $args ) {
    if ( $media ) {
        return $media;
    } else {
        $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $url = 'YOUR_CUSTOM_DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL' ;

        return array( array(
            'type'  => 'image',
            'from'  => 'custom_fallback',
            'src'   => esc_url( $url ),
            'href'  => $permalink,
        ) );
    }
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_images_get_images', 'wpse_203094_custom_image', 10, 3 );
```

Or you can use filter to change the default one.

```
function wpse_203094_jetpack_default_image() {
    return 'YOUR_IMAGE_URL';
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_open_graph_image_default', 'wpse_203094_jetpack_default_image' );
```

Or you can disable them entirely using:

```
add_filter( 'jetpack_enable_open_graph', '__return_false' );
```

## Note

As **@cjbj** pointed out that some plugins like `Yoast SEO` can override open graph tags. The above filters/code works only for `Jetpack` assuming that no other plugins are overriding them.

### Update

> Is there any solution, that would allow me to block og:image tag only for favicon

Yes there is , we can use [**`jetpack_images_get_images`**](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/4.0.3/class.jetpack-post-images.php/#L496) filter.If we take a look at [**`jetpack_og_get_image`**](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/4.0.3/functions.opengraph.php/#L340) src we can find that it adds core site icon  like this

```
// Third fall back, Core Site Icon. Added in WP 4.3.

if ( empty( $image ) && ( function_exists( 'has_site_icon') && has_site_icon() ) ) {
    $image['src']     = get_site_icon_url( 512 );
    $image['width']   = '512';
    $image['height']  = '512';
}
```

And finally defaults to blank image like this

```
// Finally fall back, blank image
if ( empty( $image ) ) {
    /**
     * Filter the default Open Graph Image tag, used when no Image can be found in a post.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $str Default Image URL.
     */
    $image['src'] = apply_filters( 'jetpack_open_graph_image_default', 'https://s0.wp.com/i/blank.jpg' );
}
```

So as to make Jetpack assume that it has already got an image and there is no need to use `site icon`, we need to set some image.This can be done using the following code.Place this in `functions.php` of the active theme.

```
function wpse_203094_no_site_icon( $media, $post_id, $args ) {
    if ( $media ) {
        return $media;
    } else {
        return array( array(
            'src'   => '' // here we are conning Jetpack, Hurray!
        ) );
    }
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_images_get_images', 'wpse_203094_no_site_icon', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Unless you have an SEO plugin like Yoast's installed. This will override Jetpack and then add its own open graph tags to the head.

Comment: Thanks @cjbj , you are correct but i can say from his site that OP is not using Yoast SEO :)

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I thought it would be good to note this for people with similar issues passing by at a later time. ;-)

Comment: @cjbj Sure, i will make a note of it.

Comment: @bravokeyl This is an awesome and great answer. To make it perfect, consider adding an information, where (to which file) one should put customized `wpse_228649_remove_image_tag` function. Plus, consider, if you can provide an answer to updated question. Thank you.

Comment: @trejder updated the answer.

Comment: @bravokeyl Thank you for a great answer. Happy to accept it. Waiting for your well earned bonus to be added. Sorry, that I can offer more, but this site is so niche, that I don't have much reputation here.

Comment: @trejder  great! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the function that is adding the meta tag (and it's added in it's own).

```
function se_remove_meta() {
 remove_action('wp_head',  'function_name');
}
add_action( 'init', 'se_remove_meta' );
```